# android ndk linking against libcutils.so

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to link an executable against libcutils.so, but I get the following error:

```
Executable     : gps_test
/home/jbrew/android_gps/jni/lib_dir//libcutils.so: undefined reference to `ioprio_set'
/home/jbrew/android_gps/jni/lib_dir//libcutils.so: undefined reference to `ioprio_get'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/gps_test] Error 1
```

Here is what my Android.mk file looks like:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= \
    gps_test.c

LOCAL_LDLIBS:= -L/home/jbrew/android_gps/jni/lib_dir/ -llog -lhardware -lcutils 

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:= \
    /home/jbrew/android_gps/jni/includes

LOCAL_MODULE:= gps_test

#include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Is there a way to get the compiler to ignore these?  I tried to add CFLAG --warn-unresolved-symbols, but the compiler didn't know what that flag meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else that has this issue, the problem was my API level.  ndk-build was using android-3 to build by default.  I added a default.properties file to my project path, then put "target=android-9" in that file.  After this addition, I could build the executable.

Comment: an easier way to choose a specific API level is to set `APP_PLATFORM:=android-9` in `Application.mk`.